# Auto connecting elements in mxgraph by dragging

Tags: diagram, mxgraph

Standard way of drawing diagrams in mxgraph is to place elements and link them together with connections.

Is it possible to create invisible connection by dragging one element onto the other? Perfectly it should work like this:

1. You have element A and B each of them have two ports. Center of the north and south of the element.
2. You drag the element B. Still you should see the element and its ports while dragging.
3. When B hovers over A the ports of A should become visible.
4. When one of B ports hover over A port the ports should get highlighted.
5. You stop dragging. The connection between previously highlighted ports is created, but is invisible since the distance is 0. The connection spot is visible (a dot?)
6. If you decide to move A or B then the connection should be visible. Should look like a standard one.
7. If you move again A or B that way that already connected ports overlap the connection should be invisible again.

[image: Autoconnecting]

I am sorry for bad quality picture, but it is best I could do.